# loading an image in pdf format using jagpdf

Tags: c++, pdf

I am using the jagpdf library (http://www.jagpdf.org/ ) to create in c++ a pdf report of some calculations I am making and the documentation says the library accept images in png, jpg and native pdf format.
An example program would be:

```
#include <jagpdf/api.h>

using namespace jag;

main()
{
    int pagewidth = 766;
    int pageheight = 589;
    pdf::Document doc(pdf::create_file("report.pdf"));
    doc.page_start(pagewidth, pageheight);
    pdf::Image imag1 = doc.image_load_file("example1.pdf");

    int imagex2 = 0;
    int imagey2 = 0;

    doc.page().canvas().image(imag1, imagex2, imagey2);
    doc.page_end();
    doc.finalize();
    return;
}
```

if I use "example1.jpg" instead of "example1.pdf" it works, but the pdf format is throwing me an exception even though documentation implies is a recognized format.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: *but the pdf format is throwing me an exception* -- Please post what the exception is.  Second, according to the site, that library comes with full source code, so you could debug it to see where and why the exception is thrown.

Comment: The exception s thrown when image_load_file is called, so is clearly not working with pdf images, but n the documentation it seems it should be able to, so I wanted to know if there is anything I can change to make it work